# Possible free() problem in my Dijkstra algorithm

Tags: c, windows-vista

I'm using Dijkstra's to find the shortest path to complete a certain puzzle, where the puzzle works as follows. You have five cyphers, which can be anywhere from -4 to 4 (although they're represented differently, as "very low/high" for -4/4, "low/high" for -3 to -1 or 1 to 3, and "completed" for 0). The objective is to set all five to 0, using the 20 different "techniques" which raise/lower the cypher values by a set amount. If a technique would modify one of the cyphers outside the bounds, i.e above 4 or below -4, then it instead does nothing. So, I've represented it as a graph, where the nodes are all the possible combinations of cypher values, and the starting node is the completed node (0,0,0,0,0). To make it easier, I'm representing the cyphers as values from 0 to 8, with 4 being the completed value - this lets me convert them base 9 into indices of the array of the graph, so there's no time wasted on searches.

Now, I've got it all banged out, and I've been debugging and trying to figure out what's wrong, and generally I'll figure a problem out and fix it fine - but this one has me stumped. I'm storing nodes which have a definite distance but which haven't been visited in a linked list, to allow for easy popping of visited nodes. When the linked list gets to 14256 nodes, it fails - but what it fails to do is a free() on the linked list element to be popped. I don't know what could cause a free() to fail and I haven't found anything to help.

I haven't asked any questions here before so I don't know the etiquette - I'm going to put the entire source in here because I don't know what is and isn't relevant in this particular situation, but it's about 140 lines which is rather large. On further perusal it appears that there isn't really a  tag or anything, so I'll just put it on codepad for now.

http://codepad.org/I0K0ETsU

Edit: Alright. Okay. Now I've become thoroughly confused. I decided to just comment it out, for giggles - and nothing else goes wrong. It finishes, spits out output.txt, and the text file appears to be perfectly correct. I can't figure out what in the hell is wrong with the code that would make it fall apart on a free() when nothing else is wrong.

Comment: Windows just shuts it down, saying "A problem has caused the program to stop working correctly."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was that I wasn't including the \0 character in the string length stuff for malloc().

Answer (score 1):

After a cursory review, it looks like pool->next is initialized to temp, and at that time, temp->next is uninitialized.  So when you walk the list to temp->next, and attempt to free it, you are freeing an uninitialized pointer (or memory you do not own).

Comment: It shouldn't attempt to free temp->next if temp->next is uninitialized (I don't think) - the root item pool's value is the total number of elements in the linked list, so the traversal over the linked list doesn't go beyond the boundary to an uninitialized pointer.

Answer (score 1):

A `free` will generally fail for only a few reasons:

- <del>Trying to free a NULL pointer</del>
- Trying to free something that's been free'd before (double free)
- Trying to free something invalid (i.e. freeing an address that is garbage)
- Memory corruption (the area that stores info about the allocated section has been overflowed into)

Comment: Just a note here, it is actually completely safe to call free on a NULL pointer.

Comment: `man 3p free`: If ptr is a null pointer, no action shall  occur. Good call, sir.